# After installing spyder django is not working

Tags: django, spyder

I installed spyder on my ubuntu system From which django is not working. The error it is showing when i ran the server the error showing is is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I need both spyder for OpenCV and also Django. can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the Django is missing from your system, if you have installed the dependencies in your `virtualenv` you will need to activate that, or you can just do

`pip install django --user`

If you have a virtualenv do this,

Linux

```
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

Windows

```
path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

First create a virtual environment, using the following command

`python3 -m virtualenv venv`

If you get an error saying something similar to this, `Virtualenv module not found`, you will need to install `virtualenv` using pip by the following command.

`pip3 install virtualenv`

Then use the aforementioned command to create the virtual environment.

To `activate` it just use

`source venv/bin/activate`

This will activate the virtual environment. Now install `Django` on it.

`pip install django`

You don't need to specify a pip version (say `pip3`) because the virtual environment is created in `python3` so `pip` defaults to `pip3` itself.

Now finally run your server

`python manage.py runserver localhost:8080`

Comment: (base) mohan@mohan:/media/mohan/216ABE293C9F84C91/projects$ source path/to/venv/bin/activate
bash: path/to/venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory

Comment: (base) mohan@mohan:/media/mohan/216ABE293C9F84C91/projects$ sudo pip3 install django --user
Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from django) (0.3.0)

Comment: The path I have mentioned in the answer is just a dummy path, you need to find your own virtual environment.

Comment: ohan@mohan:/media/mohan/216ABE293C9F84C91/projects/k/prname$ source activate
(base) mohan@mohan:/media/mohan/216ABE293C9F84C91/projects/k/prname$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Not windows but ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It is working after doing 
python3 -m pip install django

thank u mr sahil